# SQL : find data by range of date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 records with field "from_date" and "to_date" :

```
 - Record 1 : from_date=2017-05-15 and to_date=2017-06-12
 - Record 2 : from_date=2018-03-20 and to_date=2018-04-11
```

how to get Record 2 if search from date :

```
 - 2018-03-01 and 2018-03-31?
```

or

```
 - 2018-04-01 and 2018-04-30?
```

or

```
 - 2018-04-01 and 2018-04-03?
```

Comment: It depends on the condition you want. You have a range of date in your records but provide also a range of date for the condition, should the date be inclusive or exclusive ? Please propose a complete input/output example. And of course, have you tried something ?

Comment: @AxelH, i just want to get "Record 2" of all the above conditions. actually i have found the answer myself. thank btw.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i'm using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your response. I have found the answer.

```
WHERE ((from_date BETWEEN {fromDate} AND {toDate} OR to_date BETWEEN {fromDate} AND {toDate} OR (from_date <= {fromDate} AND to_date >= {fromDate}))
```

if using CakePHP3 :

```
->where([
        'OR' => [
            function($exp) use($fromDate,$toDate){                            
                return $exp->between('from_date',$fromDate,$toDate,'date');
            },
            function($exp) use($fromDate,$toDate){                            
                return $exp->between('to_date',$fromDate,$toDate,'date');
            }, 
            'AND' => [
                'from_date <=' => $fromDate,
                'to_date >=' => $fromDate
            ]
        ],
        'from_date is not' => null
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as :

```
SELECT * 
   FROM records 
    WHERE from_date >= @from_date 
         OR to_date <= @to_date
```

Where `@from_date` and `@to_date` are just your variables.

I used an `OR` since you are not looking for a inclusive range. It is just a partial match.

You want a condition that match this record `from_date=2018-03-20` and `to_date=2018-04-11`

Let's review the condition based on `WHERE from_date >= @from_date OR to_date <= @to_date`

```
@from_date = 2018-03-01 --false
@to_date   = 2018-03-31 --true
--
@from_date = 2018-04-01 --true
@to_date   = 2018-04-30 --false
--
@from_date = 2018-04-01 --true
@to_date   = 2018-04-03 --true
```

This shows that you only need one of the bounderies to match.

*Note that based on the DBMS, the date comparison can vary, but the logic remain the same.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:

```
Declare @date1 Date
Declare @date2 Date

set @date1 = <<give your first date>> 'yyyy-dd-mm
set @date2 = <<give your second date>> 'yyyy-dd-mm

SELECT * FROM tbldate WHERE CONVERT(DATE,@date1) BETWEEN from_date and to_date OR CONVERT(DATE,@date2) BETWEEN from_date and to_date
```

Answer (score 0):

oracle example:

```
with 
    table1 as 
      ( select 1 id, to_date('2017-05-15','YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2017-06-12','YYYY-MM-DD') date_to  from dual union all
        select 2 id, to_date('2018-03-20','YYYY-MM-DD') date_from, to_date('2018-04-11','YYYY-MM-DD') date_to  from dual )
select
    *
from 
    table1
where
/*
        to_date('2018-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') < date_to
    and to_date('2018-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD') > date_from

        to_date('2018-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD') < date_to
    and to_date('2018-04-30','YYYY-MM-DD') > date_from
*/
        to_date('2018-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD') < date_to
    and to_date('2018-04-03','YYYY-MM-DD') > date_from
;
```